# how to determine a log file age of log4net using powershell script

Tags: powershell, log4net, monitoring

how to determine a log file age of log4net using powershell script.as when using log4net the log file timestamp is only modified when it is closed. so monitoring cannot be setup based on  last write time on last access time

Comment: Read in the first few lines of the file, then parse out the date. If you post an example, someone might be able to assist with the parsing

Comment: 00:01:29 - Started _SendAsyncYMsg.
00:01:29 - Sending YMsg Message to Sabre
00:01:30 - YMsg Sent to Sabre
00:03:16 - Adding Irregular Op Segment: QX - 9370 - 01/01/2018 - BOI - SEA - N626QX
00:03:16 - Starting NotifyIrrops for fltsegid: 7267907
00:03:16 - Connecting to Database, Notify Irregular Ops for Fltsegid 7267907... here is some example of the log comments righ hand side will be having the timestap which gets updated every time.

Comment: Sorry i thing i put the wrong question here.. actually i want my powershell Script to generate an output based on if file is being written or not.. if file is not modified for more than 2 minutes it should display anmessage stating file not modified. When i tried to write script using lastmodifiedtime but it failed as file is continuously written but time is only modified whenbfile is closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the file to get the datetime of the fist log messages. Or you can use naming convention in your log file name.

Comment: Hi peter,Could you please guide me with more details.  how i can compare the time stamp from the parsed data with current time?